# Sorting a multidimensional array by string?

Tags: php, string, sorting, multidimensional-array

I need to sort this array by the subsubkey "description" ascending.
I tried a few methods like usort, ksort, subval_sort but none of these work (I guess the main problem is that these are strings, always)

Any help is appreciated

```
array(77) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(17) "abcd"
    ["description"]=>
    string(15) "Delete XY"
    ["level"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(13) "fgfgdgfd"
    ["description"]=>
    string(18) "Uploader XY"
    ["level"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(15) "sdfdsfsdfs"
    ["description"]=>
    string(20) "Download abc"
    ["level"]=>
    int(0)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    return strcasecmp($a['description'], $b['description']); //compare two strings ignoring case
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `SORT_STRING` option of `array_multisort` like:

```
array_multisort($ar[0], SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING,
          $ar[1], , SORT_ASC, SORT_STRING);
```